# Json object model is not updated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to update the json object model values like the code below. But it does not seems to update the model when I change the values.

I have tried removing the async code, that seems to work. why async code does not to work? Can some one please explain me. Thanks

```
var json = {
  lang: "es",
  country : "Spain", 
  city : {
    cityname : "name"
  }  
};

async function asynctranslateText() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("OK");
  });
}

async function modifyJson(en) {
  Object.keys(en).forEach(async function (item) {
    if (typeof en[item] === 'object') {
      await modifyJson(en[item]);
    } else {
      en[item] = await asynctranslateText();
    }    
  });
}

 (async () => {
  await modifyJson(json);
  console.log(json);
 })();

Output
{ lang: 'es', country: 'Spain', city: { cityname: 'name' } }

Expected output:
{ lang: 'OK', country: 'OK', city: { cityname: 'OK' } }
```

Comment: You have an await call inside `modifyJson` so this function needs to be async, your editor probably detect this error

Comment: And why do you need `async-await` here?

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and the Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: thanks. i have updated the code again. please take a look

Comment: This function `asynctranslateText` doesn't make any sense. And there is no need to put `async` in front of it.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov there is a api call, for simplicity of this example i have returned "OK"

Comment: Currently you need `modifyJson` to return a promise so that it can properly be awaited. You should change `forEach` to `map` and wrap that inside of [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @fifachapman but if it's returning a promise then you only need to await the promise itself, not the function. The function is not asynchronous as it just returns a promise to await.

Comment: Try to use regular `for loop`. If that will work out, then you need to change your current approach if you want to use `forEach`

Comment: An async function inside a foreach is probably not doing what you expect, try a `for of`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modifyJson` should return a promise in order to be `await`ed.

Since functions marked `async` implicitly return promises, you can use `Array.map` as opposed to `forEach` with an `async` function to generate an array of promises.

Then simply use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to complete.

Note that `modifyJson` and `asyncTransalateText` itself here doesn't need to be marked as `async`. Typically a function should not be marked as `async` AND return a promise.

```js
var json = {
  lang: "es",
  country: "Spain",
  city: {
    cityname: "name"
  }
};

function asynctranslateText() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("OK");
  });
}

function modifyJson(en) {
  return Promise.all(Object.keys(en).map(async function(item) {
    if (typeof en[item] === 'object') {
      await modifyJson(en[item]);
    } else {
      en[item] = await asynctranslateText();
    }
  }));
}

(async() => {
  await modifyJson(json);
  console.log(json);
})();
```

Comment: Remove `async` before `asynctranslateText` function. It can be misunderstood by newbies.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a for .. of loop to enumerate the object keys, the result will be as expected.

The original issue is that modifyJson will not have executed when we log the output.

```js
var json = {
  lang: "es",
  country : "Spain", 
  city : {
    cityname : "name"
  }  
};

async function asynctranslateText() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("OK");
  });
}

async function modifyJson(en) {
 for(let item of Object.keys(en)) {
    if (typeof en[item] === 'object') {
      await modifyJson(en[item]);
    } else {
      en[item] = await asynctranslateText();
    }
  }
}

 (async () => {
  await modifyJson(json);
  console.log(json);
 })();
```